# Multidimensional MySQL result – subqueries as arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, subquery

MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    seats,
    ( SELECT tires, bumpers FROM exterior ) AS stuff
FROM
    interior
```

The result I was expecting:

```
0 => [
    'seats' => 'comfort',
    'stuff' => [
        0 => [
            'tires' => 'winter',
            'bumpers' => 'front'
        ],
        1 => [
            'tires' => 'summer',
            'bumpers' => 'back'
        ],
        ...
    ]
],
1 => ...
```

However, this did not work. Error message: *Operand should contain 1 column(s)*.

Is possible to get the subquery results returned as arrays, the way/format the base query is? Or grouping it this way is only possible with e.g. PHP? Thanks.

Comment: Your SQL makes no sense to the DBMS. Since you have provided an example of what you were expecting then we can make some guesses about what the SQL should look like, but the example output raises as many questions as it answers. Perhaps you could show us what data in what tables you expect to result in the output.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for this would be the following:

```
SELECT seats,
( SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',tires, bumpers) FROM exterior ) AS stuff
FROM interior

// Where $array would be the result of the query

function stringtoarray($string) {
    return explode(',',$string);
}

for($i=0;!empty($array);$i++) {
    $array[''stuff'] = stringtoarray($array[''stuff']);
}
```

I realize they don't have the key value yet, but you should be able to fix this within this method as well.

Comment: Wouldn't this be too slow? @Jester

Answer (score 0):

As your "exterior" table has multiple rows, so you can't alias multiple row like this: `( SELECT tires, bumpers FROM exterior ) AS stuff`
Either use limit in your sub-query or let me know where there is any relation between "interior" & "exterior" table.If any relation exists, then use `join`

Comment: While this will prevent the query from executing as Osvaldas expects, it is not the cause of the error message - the error is occurring during parsing as it trie to return more than one column of data.